# can't make checkbox checked

Tags: java, android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I need your help please to finish my first android project, my objective is to set the status of checkbox depending on preferences, so this is what I tried :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxfriendRequests"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="   Friend requests"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
         faceFrag = new FacebookFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, faceFrag)
            .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            faceFrag = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }

        ActionBar myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        myActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout_face);



        // get view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(FacebookActivity.this);
        final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facebook, null);

        // set sharedPrefernces editor
        facePrefs = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        // checkBoxfriendRequests status
        checkBoxfriendRequests = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxfriendRequests);



        if(facePrefs.getBoolean("friendRequest", false)){
            checkBoxfriendRequests.setChecked(true);
            Log.d("sami","checkbox is cheked");
        }
        else{
            checkBoxfriendRequests.setChecked(false);
            Log.d("sami","checkbox is uncheked");
        }


}


 public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkBoxfriendRequests :
                                    // add to preferences
                editor.putBoolean("friendRequest", checked );
                editor.commit();    
                if(checked) 
                    Log.d("sami", " checked true" );
                else
                    Log.d("sami", " checked false" );

                break;
        .....
    }

}
```

on activity creation I can see in the LogCat that the checkbox is correctly checked/uncheked but visualy it start always unchecked whatever is the preference parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution :**
add this lines to onCreateView  (fragment) :

```
facePrefs = this.getActivity().getPreferences(0);
editor = this.getActivity().getPreferences(0).edit();
```

then we can access checkbox from fragment class not from activity.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you haven't accidentally disabled your checkbox:

```
checkbox.setEnabled(false);
```

That was my mistake when I meant to set it as not checked:

```
checkbox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

in `public void onCheckboxClicked(View view)`

use

```
boolean checked = checkBoxfriendRequests.isChecked();
```

even the view is Checkbox you still need to use findViewById first

Solution 2:

remove `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

```
checkBoxfriendRequests= (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxfriendRequests);
checkBoxfriendRequests.setChecked(facePrefs.getBoolean("friendRequest", false));
checkBoxfriendRequests.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
            editor.putBoolean("friendRequest", arg1);
            editor.commit();
        }
});
```

Comment: problem still unsolved, even if: facePrefs.getBoolean("friendRequest", false) == true , the checkbox doesn't turn checked on activity creation.

Comment: I think maybe is the way you call `LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(FacebookActivity.this); final View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_facebook, null);` is wrong so the view is not responded.